# как получить свойство из объекта вложенного в объект

Tags: javascript, jquery

консоль выдаёт следующие объект
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
у каждого вложенного объекта есть свойство gid 
как мне получить массив из этого свойства?

```
gid=[]
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){                  
        for(j=0;j<data.length;j++){
            if(data[i][j]=="gid")gid.push(data[i][j])
        }
    }
```

Comment: что не так с кодом в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy Cannot read property 'length' of undefined а если пишу вместо  gid.push(data[i][j]) пишу console.log(data[i][j]) то undefined

Comment: очевидно _data_ = _undefined_ - вам нужно бежать по чему-то еще

Comment: $.each(data,function(key,val){ console.log(val.gid) }) сделайте так

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich сам у себя ошибку найдешь? Из того массива который на скрине, и твой комментарий

Comment: Если правильно подготовить массив то ошибки нет

Comment: Вот собственно вдруг кому пригодится http://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/Mewbro?editors=1111

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich причем тут это, ты заведомо сделал ошибку в коде, который упадет. Проверки делать времени не хватает или что?) Это же всего одно условие. Добавь свой ответ. Он пока самый нормальный (если конечно добавишь условие)

Answer (score 1):

data[i][j] и будет Undefined.

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    gid.push(data[i].gid);
}
```

Comment: в коде из вопроса свойство `length` вызывается только у `data`

Answer (score 0):

Из объекта вложенного в объект который находиться в массиве можно так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var arg in data[i]){     
        if(arg === 'gid'){
                    // какие-то действия;
        }

      }
}
```

дико извиняюсь про jquery не досмотр... Ответ чистый JS...

Comment: Брррррррррррррррррр...

Comment: что за ерунда, зачем 2 цикла? И зачем перебирать каждое свойство объекта в цикле? Вы что не можете проверить на существование нужное свойство и записать его, если оно есть? К чему этот второй цикл вообще?